# Is it possible for Jbgallery 3.0 slideshow animation to fade from white

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried looking through jbgallery-3.0.js to find the option to fade the animation from white instead of black but can't find it anywhere. Anyone have any ideas on how I could do this.

This is the gallery the site is using: http://www.ymic3dworld.com/lightwindow2/jbgallery-3.0/index.html

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a result of the images being overlaid on a black background? I would imagine the library just changes the opacity of the images to fade them in. Have you tried this on your own page with a white background?

Comment: In fact, I just tested this theory on the jbgallery page by removing the black background color with chrome's element inspector, and it works.

Comment: I changed the body background to white but it still is fading to black for some reason. This is the site: http://www.post-pro.ca/

Comment: It's not just the body background that needs to be changed. It's any background on any element containing the photos, all the way out to and including the body. If you remove the photos and you see black where they would be, the CSS still needs to be changed some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Further to my comments above)

This CSS rule should fix it on your site:

```
body.jbg-body, .jbgallery, .jbgallery .jbg-wrap {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

This should override those CSS rules that are being included by jbgallery-3.0.css which are making the background of the image gallery area black.

Comment: Awesome! Found that     

html.jbg-body,body.jbg-body,.jbgallery,.jbgallery .jbg-wrap     table,.jbgallery .jbg-wrap td{background:#fff;font-family:FreeSans,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;width:100%;height:100%; margin:0;padding:0px;} was the culprit! Thanks so much!